# C++17 constexpr array matrices and functors compatible by overloading operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, containers, c++17, constexpr

I am trying to make two types of objects compatible by using a container, to make it more difficult, my code must be able to calculate at compile time.

One of my objects type is structured as a functor in the following way:

```cpp
template <std::size_t n,std::size_t p=1,typename number=double>
class Oper{
    public:
    constexpr Oper(const number d_=1.):d(d_){}
    constexpr Oper(const Oper& oper_):d(oper_.d){}
    const number d ;
    constexpr auto operator()(const auto &v) const {
    typename std::remove_const<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(v)>::type>::type w{} ;
        /* Do some stuff to build w using v and d*/
    return w ;}
};
```

The other object type is just `std::array<std::array<double,n>,n>`, i.e. matrices.

These objects are provided with the following operators as free functions:

```cpp
template <std::size_t nr, std::size_t nc>
constexpr auto
operator *(const std::array<std::array<double,nc>,nr> & A,
           const std::array<double,nc> & x){
    std::array<double,nr> res{};
    for (auto i=0u;i<nr;i++)
        for (auto j=0u;j<nc;j++)
            res[i] += A[i][j]*x[j];
    return res;
}

template <std::size_t nrA, std::size_t ncA, std::size_t nrB, std::size_t ncB>
constexpr auto operator *(const std::array<std::array<double,ncA>,nrA> & A,
                          const std::array<std::array<double,ncB>,nrB> & B){
    std::array<std::array<double,ncB>,nrA> res{};
    for (auto k=0u;k<ncB;++k)
        for (auto i=0u;i<nrA;++i)
            for (auto j=0u;j<nrB;++j)
                res[i][k] += A[i][j]*B[j][k];
    return res ;
}

constexpr auto operator *(const auto & A,const auto & x){
    return A(x) ;
}
```

Bear in mind I cannot change these implementations, they are provided to me.

To make these operators compatible I created the following classes

```cpp
constexpr auto id = [](const auto v) {return v;};

template <typename Op, typename Preop=decltype(id)>
class Cont{
public:
    constexpr Cont(const Op & op_,const Preop & preop_=id):op(op_),preop(preop_){}
    constexpr Cont(const Cont & cont_):op(cont_.op),preop(cont_.preop){}
    const Op op ;
    const Preop preop ;
    template <typename Op2, typename Preop2>
    constexpr auto operator()(const Cont<Op2,Preop2> & mfop) const{
        return Cont<const Cont<Op,Preop>,const Cont<Op2,Preop2>>
               (Cont(op,preop),mfop);}
    constexpr auto operator()(const auto & v) const{return op*(preop*v);}
};
```

Such that the following main compiles and works as expected

```cpp
int main(){
    const std::array<double,4> v{};
    const Cont A(Oper<4,1>(1.));
    const Cont B(std::array<std::array<double,4>,4>{std::array<double,4>{}});
    constexpr auto res = B*B*A*A*B*A*B*v;
    return 0;
}
```

Godbolt example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9050Ck).

I am having issues with the `Cont` class

1. The idea of `Cont` when using functors only (no arrays), is to somehow place the code corresponding to different functors one after the other and, ideally, optimize the whole chain. Can that be achieved? How should I do it? Maybe some perfect forwarding magic?
2. There are many copies being done in `Cont`, this is causing a huge memory footprint of the compiler (GCC 8.2.0 with flags `-std=c++1z -fconcepts -Ofast`) when asking for a full compile time calculation. I believe this is because of all the copies being performed when putting the operators together. Could that be possible? Is there a way to avoid the copy?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of `cosnt` data members being used. Is there a particular reason for that?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for your comment. It is a requirement to me that the code must be able to run at compile time if need be. This is the reason for all the `const` types. Feel free to change them otherwise, however, the implementations of `Oper` and the operators `*` are provided to me, I can only play with `Cont` or add things to the implementation.

Comment: A `class` can be used at compile time even if it has non-`const` data members. Having  a `constexpr` constructor is enough. And having `const` data member has a lot of down sides. Your type can't be assigned to and your type may be harder to move from. It makes it difficult to store in a container.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for your comment. Feel free to change them in `Cont` or any other new class needed if you can keep compile time capabilities. The rest of the implementation is provided to me, so I can't do much with it.

Comment: I don't understand your first issue. Isn't your code already OK? What do you expect to be achieved?

Comment: @xskxzr Thanks for your comment. I'd expect to eliminate the need of the many copies performed in the process of building the `Cont` instantiation corresponding to the complete multiplication chain and ensure that the chain of operators is optimized as a whole. My guess is that the way is to use perfect forwarding somehow but I don't know how. Then, the second issue is to know if those copies are indeed the cause of the increase on the memory footprint of the compiler.